# Where to find Mongo Stitch AppID?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I can't for life find my app id in mongo stitch service.

Does anyone know where is it located?

According to documentation it should be on the Client page of Stitch UI. I'm looking for it everywhere, but just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, here it is:[image: On Realm (new Stitch) UI]

It's not obvious where it is, so here's a picture!

Answer (score 0):

Found it under Stitch UI Settings